# How can I remove older records from a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

How can I remove older documents from a collection, older than seven days?

```
{ "orderID" : "456986", "orderType" : "OnlinePurchase", "orderStatus" : "expired", "address" : "Hexel", "payement" : "Card", "isDomestic" : true, "orderExpDate" : ISODate("2017-09-20T20:36:11.000Z"), "shipped" : false }
```

Comment: what is document structure ?? Edit with more details

Comment: {  
    "orderID" : "456986",
    "orderType" : "OnlinePurchase",
    "orderStatus" : "expired",
    "address" : "Hexel",
    "payement" : "Card",
    "isDomestic" : true,
    "orderExpDate" : ISODate("2017-09-20T20:36:11.000Z"),
    "shipped" : false
} ----- I would like to remove all documents whose orderExpDate is seven days older from today's date

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`db.collection.remove` has been deprecated. You should use:
`db.collection.deleteMany( { orderExpDate : {"$lt" : new Date(2017, 9, 1) } }))`

Comment: What if I want to delete all documents from the last 48 hours?

Comment: You could use $gt instead of $lt. Then your date object would need to be equal to 2 days before.

Answer (score 23):

For removing documents before Date, your command should be:

```
db.collection.deleteMany( { orderExpDate : {"$lt" : new Date(YEAR, MONTH, DATE) } })
```

For removing records *before* 1 October 2017, the command will be:

```
db.collection.deleteMany( { orderExpDate : {"$lt" : new Date(2017, 9, 1) } })
```

October is the 10th month. If the month field is zero indexed, then we use 9, otherwise use 10.

...........................

This will remove all records older than seven *days*:

```
db.collection.deleteMany( { orderExpDate : {"$lt" : new Date(Date.now() - 7*24*60*60 * 1000) } })
```

**Update:** collection.remove is deprecated

Comment: In this query how it will remove exact 7 days ago data from today's date

Comment: Try :  `db.collection.remove( { orderExpDate : {"$lt" : lastWeek } })`

Comment: ReferenceError: lastWeek is not defined :

Comment: Yes, thank you S N Tiwari, your solution worked. Is there any other way to work around.