# Delete MongoDB document after n days in go

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I want to delete user accounts after 3 days if they don't verify their email. As a scheduler would be inefficient, I'm searching for a way to schedule this delete in MongoDB. I also need a way to cancel it, if the user verifies the email.

I'm using mgo as api for MongoDB and I'm running latest Go (1.9).

Comment: [Expire Data from Collections by Setting TTL](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) Kind of the first search result really.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB : How to remove older records from a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441006/mongodb-how-to-remove-older-records-from-a-collection)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved in MongoDB version 3.4

You can use mongodb's [TTL](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/) index along with [partial index expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#partial-indexes).

Try adding following index on `users` collection:

```
db.users.ensureIndex(
{ created_at:1}, 
{ expireAfterSeconds:259200, 
  partialFilterExpression:{"verified" : false}})
```

This TTL index with delete all those users who are not verified and it has been 3 days since they were added.

Comment: Thanks. Is it also possible to remove this check when someone verified his account? So mongodb doens't check this everytime. Also is the expireAfterSeconds relative to the time I created the document or to the time I executed this command?

Comment: For first part, you have to update this from app side(set verified to true when a user accepts it). expireAfterSec refers to time you created the doc.

Comment: @Florian The background process running TTL expieries runs every minute, no matter what (iirc, even when there isn't a TTL index). No need to worry.

Comment: now used as createIndex as of 2020, expire helped ...